# empaquetar una aplicacion de forma mas ligera

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Estoy haciendo un programa en python y quiero empaquetarlo en un .exe. Para ello uso el conocido "pyinstaller". No es la primera vez que lo utlizo.

El problema es que ahora quiero empaquetar el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando y el archivo final pesa mas o menos 38 MB. Seria normal en un juego o una aplicacion mas o menos grande pero la mia tiene unas cuantas ventanas y ya.

Tengo la sospecha que el pyinstaller empaqueta TODAS las librerias que incluyo, pues de otra forma no me explico porque pesa tanto.

Quisiera saber si hay otra forma de empaquetar que no sea pyinstaller o hay alguna forma de configurarlo para que sea mas ligero.

No se mucho al respecto pero se que mi programa no deberia pesar tanto ya que el mismo programa hecho en autoit apenas pesaria unos cuantos kilobytes.
De antemano muchas gracias cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar. 
Estare aqui todo el tiempo.

Comment: Dependiendo de los módulos que incorpores 38Mb es un  número razonable. un "Hola mundo" con pyinstaller y comprimido con upx no te va a bajar de 4/5 Mb.

Comment: mmm lo entiendo. Conoces otro metodo para empaquetar diferente a pyinstaller??

Comment: Puedes probar otros métodos, como cx_freeze o Nuitka (este último crea código C++ y lo compila). Saludos :)